# Java heap space error in uploading document through webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

HI

I am uploading the documents through webservice into the server.. when i am uploading the <10MB file, it is working fine & it is >10MB it is thrown the following error in the console..

I had the using the following parameters in the eclipse..

```
-startup
plugins/org.
clipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
--256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
--512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx384m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=300m
-XX:MaxPermSize=300m
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
```

I am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The file was uploading the server with 0KB..

Any one can help me resolve this issue

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Increase the value of your `-Xmx` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you allocating so much `PermGen` space (`--launcher.XXMaxPermSize --512m` and `-XX:PermSize=300m` and `-XX:MaxPermSize=300m`)?  Virtually nothing needs that much `PermGen` space.  Most applications don't need more than 128M.  If you have a server for a complex application that's meant to run forever then you *may* be justified in increasing the value to 256M.  But 512M is unnecessary.

I would suggest reducing these three options to 256M (or even 128M), and then replacing `-Xmx384m` with `-Xmx512m` and seeing if that resolves the issue.